# Unexpected reactivity while using multiple reactiveVal in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am experiencing unexpected behavior while using multiple reactiveVal's in Shiny. I am aware of the existence of reactiveValues, which will likely solve my problem, but I would still like to find out why this behavior is occuring. In the code below, I have two reactiveVals:

- **reval1**, which is updated every second
- **reval2**, which never changes value.

my_plot is only dependent on reval2. Therefore I would expect it to never invalidate. However, the plot changes every second. In the [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveVal.html), I don't see any mention of the impossibility of using two reactiveVal's. Am I misinterpreting or overlooking something?

---

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  set.seed(1)
  reval1<- reactiveVal(runif(1)) # useful
  reval2 <- reactiveVal(runif(1)) # useless

  # update reval1 every second
  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(intervalMs = 1000, session = session) 
  observeEvent(autoInvalidate(),{
    reval1(reval1()+1)
  })

  # plot is only dependent on reval2.
  output$my_plot<- renderPlot({
    a<- reval2()
    df= data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10))
    plot(df$x,df$y)
  })

}

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    plotOutput("my_plot")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue. and should be fixed in the new version of shiny. There are already fixes implemented in the dev version. Note I haven't tested it myself...

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/1712

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1710

Comment: Since you have an analytics company that is based on shiny it would be good for you to look at the github page too as they have new issues there. Also subscribe to this group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shiny-discuss

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to that group, very useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is really interesting, I would even submit a bug in this case. I tried to re-write that as

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  set.seed(1)
  reval1 <- reactiveVal(runif(1)) # useful
  reval2 <- reactiveVal(runif(1)) # useless

  # update reval1 every second
  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(intervalMs = 1000) 
  observe({
    autoInvalidate()
    reval1(reval1() + 1)
    print(reval1())
  })

  # plot is only dependent on reval2.
  output$my_plot<- renderPlot({
    a <- reval2()
    df <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10))
    plot(df$x, df$y)
  })

}
```

An put it some browsers and in this, the plot does not even render. Also you can see that during the runtime the `observe()` and `output$my_plot` get fired in a loop and consistently with much shorter time than 1000ms! By the way this is the reactivity plot:

[image: Reactivity plot]